# ASP.NET Web API : how can we pass / as parameter value to action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My controller action method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAllInventoryData")]
public IHttpActionResult GetInventoryData(string DecpName)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch(Excception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

In some cases, the parameter value can have a `/` in its value, for ex `'EEPS/RA'`. When I pass such a value, I get an error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: .NET Framework and classic ASP or .NET Core with ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Use POST instead of get parameter

Comment: @GuruStron .NET Core

Comment: You need to [URL Encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) your value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the catch-all parameter (which is not suitable for all cases):

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAllInventoryData/{**DecpName}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetInventoryData(string DecpName)
{
    // ..
}
```

Another approach is to pass the encoded value `EEPS%2FRA` and manually decode it:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAllInventoryData/{DecpName}")]
public string GetInventoryData(string DecpName)
{
    return WebUtility.UrlDecode(DecpName);
}
```

Read more:

- [Routing with special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#routing-with-special-characters)
- [URL Decode in Web API pipeline doesn't decode %2F to /](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23633) github issue
- [Route templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-templates)

P.S.

Passing value as query string parameter works for me as is - `controller/GetAllInventoryData?DecpName=qweqwe/qw`

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use a query sting instead of  route parameters. Your url could be

```
.../GetAllInventoryData?decpname=EEPS/RA
```

there is another way , as it was offered by @GuruStron. You can encode 'EEPS/RA' as EEPS%2FRA and decode after

```
string DecpName = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("EEPS/RA"); 
.../GetAllInventoryData/DecpName

[HttpGet("GetAllInventoryData/{DecpName}")]
public  IHttpActionResult GetInventoryData(string decpName)
{
    var DecpName= WebUtility.UrlDecode(DecpName));
...
}
```

Comment: Where do i encode it on the front end or in the Api  controller ? I am calling the API from Angular

Comment: @Codev you can preprocess it there.

Comment: @Codev Pls post your angular code that calls an API